# Site is horizontal scrolling on mobile Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I have a responsive site that works perfectly fine on all desktop browsers as well as mobile Chrome, resizing the way I want no matter how narrow the window gets, but I'm getting a horizontal scroll on mobile Firefox. My content is just slightly too big, although I can't imagine how with my CSS. Here's what I believe is relevant:

```
#main {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.infoSection {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.infoSection img {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  max-width: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 470px) {

.infoSection {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 30px;
}

.infoSection img {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    transform: none;
}
}
```

Existing questions about horizontal scrolling on mobile all seem to involve setting overflow-x to hidden, which doesn't help because I want my content to resize properly. :/

Comment: Did you try vendor specific properties for `transform`? Such as `-moz-transform`

Comment: That shouldn't be it; it's the newest version of Firefox, which doesn't require a prefix, plus it cancels out with the media query. I just tried anyway though, and no luck...

Comment: I have the same problem... only on firefox mobile does this happen